# Python: what is the most efficient way to print a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, performance, printing, nested-lists

Specifically, I have a list like so: `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]` and I want to print it out like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

I thought that something like this would be pretty efficient:

```py
    a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]    
    for sublist in a:
        print(*sublist)
```

But it is not as efficient as I would have hoped, in very large cases. I'm dealing with thousands of sublists, and each of those are themselves thousands of numbers long.

I could have the sublists already processed so the numbers are strings or integers, that part doesn't matter too much. I just need to my code running faster, and at the moment, printing is what is taking the longest.

Comment: What is the point of printing "thousands of sublists thousands of numbers long"?

Comment: Also you can use   say an interval to save them e.g `[[1,3],[4,6],[7,9],[10]`

Comment: @DYZ Not immediately obvious, I know - but these are the sorts of hoops compsci students must jump through!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh are you able to put back up your answer? I reloaded the page and it was gone. I wasn't the one who downvoted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the overhead of printing comes from "setting up" and "tearing" down the print logic, so to speak. Therefore, if you combine everything into one long string and then print it, it should be much faster:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, sub)) for sub in a))
```

My time profiling results, given the following data, and three solutions:

```
a = [list(range(10)), list(range(10, 20)), list(range(20, 30))]    

# OP's original solution
%timeit for sublist in a: print(*sublist)
# 1.74 ms ± 89.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# another answer's solution
%timeit res = [' '.join(map(str,item)) for item in a]; print(*res, sep='\n')
# 191 µs ± 17.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# my solution
%timeit print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, sub)) for sub in a))
# 78.2 µs ± 5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh The explanation of *why* joining makes it faster, as well as the outer `join` call, which leads to a 2-4x speedup, based on my tests.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

Start by joining the inner lists as a string to make a list of strings.

Then use iterator unpacking to unpack the inner lists, and use `\n` as a separator.

```
li = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]

#Join the inner lists as a string to make a list of strings
#Print them using newline separator
print(*[' '.join(map(str,item)) for item in li], sep='\n')
```

The output is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

Also it doesn't make sense to print `thousands of sublists, and each of those are themselves thousands of numbers` as @DYZ mentioned in the comment, you can use say an interval to save them e.g `[[1,3],[4,6],[7,9],[10]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That does shave just a little off my run time. By the way, you forgot the * in your code, in the print statement, before the list comprehension.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for letting me know. @SonicProtein. If the answer helped you. please consider marking it as accepted :) Also if you want to just print the sublists with the `[]` that will not need the `join`, not sure if you want it that way though

Comment: The list of lists comes from a very large digraph, so I can't just use ranges like that unfortunately... Sorry, I should have been clearer in the question. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer, but I've upvoted you.

Comment: Sure, I think most of the other posters will hint you to not use such arrays though like one of the comments above, Or perhaps it's time to redisgn that digraph, also I am unsure why you want to print them in the first place @SonicProtein :)

Comment: Any ideas on a better approach than using arrays like that? I first manipulate a digraph, and then print the output. The printing takes by far the longest time, far longer than the graph manipulation, which is why I'm thinking about how to optimize the printing - but maybe I'm wrong to begin with, as you say, and should be thinking about not using arrays like that. 

The thing is, this is a problem that my class at uni is working on, and it apparently IS possible to do it in less time while still using a list of lists. (and that is why I need to print out so much output - it is for uni)

Comment: So this information is independent of the question asked, which is `what is the most efficient way to print a list of lists?` which as you have mentioned, my answer did optimize it a bit, also how the digraph looks like, how can you improve on it, might be matter of another question altogether, and I suggest posting a new one for the same @SonicProtein :)